# How does the box 2d ambient light work?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I used RayHandler.useDiffuseLight(true) and now my unlighted part of the screen is black no matter what ambient light value I set. Is this normal? I have seen other application made with libgdx which use both diffuse light and ambient light and it works fine... How do I get the ambient light to work with diffuse light? If I don't use diffuse light the quality of the textures is very poor as the light doesn't combine with the texture color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem while working on a day and night switch. Instead of using `RayHandler.setAmbientLight(float light)` you have to use `RayHandler.setAmbientLight(float r,float g,float b,float alfa)`It worked for me.
hope it was helpfully

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting Ambient light after setting DiffuseLight to true?
like:

```
torchLight.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
RayHandler.useDiffuseLight(true);
rayHandler.setAmbientLight(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.7f, 0.1f);
```